# How to draw a table with three cells beside two cells?

Tags: multirow

I want to draw a table with three cells beside two cells

like this ??

```
|           |           |
|:---------:|           |
|           |:---------:|
|:---------:|           |
|           |           |
|           |           |
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tabularray`-based example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec={ll}, vspan=even}
  Column1 & Column2  \\
  \multirow{2}{=}{Row1} & \multirow{3}{=}{Cell1}  \\ 
                        &                         \\
  \multirow{2}{=}{Row2} &                         \\ 
                        & \multirow{3}{=}{Cell1}  \\ 
  \multirow{2}{=}{Row3} &                         \\
                        &                         \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```